# Is there any limit to create Apple ids through iTunes on a computer?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, itunes-store

I need to know that is there any Apple account/id creation limit through iTunes from a computer?

Comment: Enlighten us, why would you like to know that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit of Apple ID creating attempts through iTunes on the MAC computer. I personally helped more than 80 people to create a new Apple ID without credit card. No problem!
There is a limit of 3 attempts for Apple ID activation on any Apple gadget (iPhone, iPad, iPod or MAC). Activation process occur when you enter new Apple ID account info into Settings > iCloud for the first time.
This limit can not be reset... Even if you ask Apple support team, they will refuse to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. And if there is, you can always switch between multiple iTunes libraries you create on the same PC via the [SHIFT + Start feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1589).

How many are you looking at creating?